# How to prevent conflict between dropdown and other links in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, overlap, foreground

I have two navbars on the left side of my page.
Until I put some links into the right navbar everything worked fine.
However once text was added into the right navbar, problems with the dropdown menus occured.
Links in the dropdown and the rightmost navbar seem to conflict, as I can't click on the submenus of my principal navbar anymore.
I tried looking for some property to bring the dropdown to the foreground but couldn't find anything useful.

[image: This is the overlapping problem]

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\styles\1navbar.css"> 
<title>  - PROCEDURE </title>
</head>


<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-left">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="../../index.html">HOME  </a><br> 

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">MENU 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="..\1File\11dde.html">MENU 1</a></li> 
      <li><a href="..\1File\12dde.html">MENU 1</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">

      <ul class="nobulet" role="menu" id="navliTOP">
            <li><a href="#evan1">MENU 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#evan2">MENU 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#evan3">MENU 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#evan4">MENU 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#evan5">MENU 1<br></a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>



    <div class="col-sm-7">

<h1> PROCEDURE </h1>
    <p>
    reter   ter
    tealter     tabindexert <br>
    radtre  tabindexertt
    er
    </p>

<!--ne plus toucher ci-après-->
    <div class="col-sm-2">
     </div>



    </div> 
  </div> 
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS (I cleaned it up as well as I can)

```
/* ________________________________________________________________________________________ */

/* Pour Fixer la bar de navigation à gauche */

.navbar-fixed-left {
  width: 140px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar-fixed-left + .container {
  padding-left: 160px;
}

/* On using dropdown menu (To right shift popuped) */
.navbar-fixed-left .navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 140px;
}

/* Fin du CSS pour la bar de navigation à gauche */

.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu { 
background-color: white; 
}

/* ________________________________________________________________________________________ */


/* Links in NavMenu */

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 140px;
}

nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#navliTOP{
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Your Bootstrap version is missing.

Comment: share your complete working example so that it will be resolve your issue

Comment: looks like a z-index problem, maybe try to give z-index to menu dropdown, if that does not work, share your work on codepen or something similar

Comment: @ClaudiuD. i don't think it's a `z-index` problem. It looks like a missing background color problem.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu without the code somewhere to check it out, i guess we can't really be sure :)

Comment: @Bhuwan I edited with the complete code

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I tried to add a css background color but it didn't fix the issue

Comment: @Lay you need to share your css as well...

Comment: @Lay, your code is ***not complete***. We have no idea what's inside `1navbar.css`, `2textcss.css` and `4tables.css`. You should add their contents in the CSS panel. But make sure you remove any styles that do not affect the described issue.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I added the CSS and cleaned it up as well as I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should solve your problem

```
.navbar-fixed-left {
z-index:1;
}
```

```css
/* ________________________________________________________________________________________ */


/* Pour Fixer la bar de navigation à gauche */

.navbar-fixed-left {
  width: 140px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 0;
  height: 100%;
z-index:1;
}

.navbar-fixed-left+.container {
  padding-left: 160px;
}


/* On using dropdown menu (To right shift popuped) */

.navbar-fixed-left .navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-left: 140px;
}


/* Fin du CSS pour la bar de navigation à gauche */

.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: white;
}


/* ________________________________________________________________________________________ */


/* Links in NavMenu */

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 140px;
}

nav li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#navliTOP {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..\styles\1navbar.css">
  <title> - PROCEDURE </title>
</head>


<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-1">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-left">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="../../index.html">HOME  </a><br>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">MENU 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="..\1File\11dde.html">MENU 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="..\1File\12dde.html">MENU 1</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-2">

        <ul class="nobulet" role="menu" id="navliTOP">
          <li><a href="#evan1">MENU 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#evan2">MENU 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#evan3">MENU 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#evan4">MENU 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#evan5">MENU 1<br></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>



      <div class="col-sm-7">

        <h1> PROCEDURE </h1>
        <p>
          reter ter tealter tabindexert <br> radtre tabindexertt er
        </p>

        <!--ne plus toucher ci-après-->
        <div class="col-sm-2">
        </div>



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```